# Pasar texto y HTML a componente hijo con ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un componente que renderiza un *título* y una *descripción* que recibe por `props`.

La descripción, la estoy *componiendo* en el componente padre a partir de varios datos, por lo que tiene texto, y algunas *etiquetas HTML*, como `br`, `strong`, ... Es algo como:

```
const description = 'Esto es una <strong>descripción</strong>'
    + '<br>'
    + 'que he añadido.'
```

Envió este contenido al hijo por *props*:

```
const description = 'Esto es una <strong>descripción</strong>'
    + '<br>'
    + 'que he añadido.'

return (
    <div className="este-es-el-componente-padre">
        <h3>Añado contenido</h3>

        <ComponenteHijo title="Esto es un título" description={description} />
    </div>
);
```

El `ComponenteHijo` original recibe texto plano para la descripción:

```
return (
    <div className="este-es-el-componente-hijo">
        <h4>{props.title}</h4>

        <p>{props.description}</p>
    </div>
)
```

Al pasar etiquetas HTML se *pintan* junto con el texto:

```
Esto es un título

Esto es una <strong>descripción</strong><br>que he añadido.
```

Entonces, he tenido que modificar `ComponenteHijo` con [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) para que la descripción se renderice correctamente:

```
return (
    <div className="este-es-el-componente-hijo">
        <h4>{props.title}</h4>

        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.description }} />
    </div>
)
```

¿Existe otra forma de hacer esto **sin tener que hacer modificaciones en el componente que va a recibir el texto con tags HTML**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias hacer esto, para que no pases una cadena de texto, sino jxs.

```
const description = <div>Esto es una <strong>descripción</strong><br/> que he añadido</div>
```

Con esta opcion se agregaria el div, pero si no quieres el div, ya que es algo inecesario para tu caso, podrias usar `Fragment`

```
const description = <React.Fragment>Esto es una <strong>descripción</strong><br/> que he añadido</React.Fragment>
```

Comment: Tu solución responde a mi pregunta, puedo **pasar texto y HTML por *props* sin modificar el componente que lo recibe**. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa posible es utilizar la utilidad [React HTML Parser](https://github.com/wrakky/react-html-parser). La misma puede ser instalada con `npm`:

```
npm install react-html-parser
```

Luego invocas `ReactHtmlParser()` dentro del componente pasando la cadena de texto que contiene etiquetas HTML como argumento:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactHtmlParser from "react-html-parser";

const description = `Esto es una <strong>descripción</strong>
<br>que he añadido`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="padre">
      <Hijo title="Titulo" description={description} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Hijo = props => {
  return (
    <div className="hijo">
      <h4>{props.title}</h4>
      <p>{ReactHtmlParser(props.description)}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

El uso de [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) es recomendable ya que no tienes que usar `+` para concatenar cadenas de texto.

Ejemplo [aquí](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-jackson-hu918)

Comment: Esto no es exactamente lo que buscaba, pero es una **buena alternativa al uso de              `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` que *puede presentar problemas de seguridad***. Sólo un apunte: mejor instalar localmente: `npm install react-html-parser --save`. Y si usas *Typescript* hay que añadir además los tipos de la librería: `npm install @types/react-html-parser --save`

Comment: `npm install` ya no no necesita que le pases `--save`, [automáticamente instala el paquete como dependencia del proyecto](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/161081169345/v500) desde la versión 5.0.0 en adelante.

Comment: @Juan_Marco bueno es saberlo